# MYSQL using LIKE for a specific search

Tags: mysql, string, search, sql-like

I've come across a search situation that I am unsure how to approach. I am searching through a set of a column which is a string for example

```
Row 1: Column Content: 7;15;25
Row 2: Column Content: 5
Row 3: Column Content: 5;7
```

but I would like the row that has only 5

example: `Select * from table where column like '%5%'`

The problem with this case is that, the query will bring back all rows when I only needed Row 2 and Row 3

Is there anything that I could do with the query that will allow me to bring back the desired results.

I would truly appreciate the assistance. If there is any confusion with the question, I'll be happy clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
CONTENT LIKE '5;%'      -- Starts with 5
OR CONTENT LIKE '%;5;%' -- 5 in the middle somewhere
OR CONTENT LIKE '%;5'   -- Ends with 5
OR CONTENT = '5';       -- 5 is the only item in the list
```

You could also simplify it as:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE concat(';',CONTENT,';') LIKE '%;5;%';
```

Both of these solutions will probably result in fairly poor performance, especially if your table is huge.  To solve that, I'd recommend normalizing this data and storing each selection as a row in another table.

Comment: The first one worked best with the table i am using. I agree with you about the normalizing part. lol. Thank you so much. :)